# Possible to create a single multi-type collection of multi-type lambda functions in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, dictionary, lambda

For instance, something like:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<T1, T2, bool>> comparisons;
    comparisons.add("<", (x, y) => x < y);
    comparisons.add("==", (x, y) => x == y);
    comparisons.add(">", (x, y) => x > y);
```

At this point, I don't know enough about C# lambdas and multi-type generic containers to be able to put this together correctly.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Look at the [`Predicate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx) delegate.

Comment: do you really want to have generic types `T1` and `T2`? You will never be able to compare those...

Comment: @jeroenh Yes, I would like to keep it as generic as possible.  Part of the appeal is making this block so succinct.  Guffa's answer looks like it addresses this by replacing T1 and T2 with IComparable and using the CompareTo() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic types has to be known at compile time, so you can't make dynamic delegate. If you specify a data type, you can create a dictionary of delegates:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>> comparisons;
comparisons.add("<", (x, y) => x < y);
comparisons.add("==", (x, y) => x == y);
comparisons.add(">", (x, y) => x > y);
```

You can use the `IComparable` interface to allow for different types, but then you can only use it's `CompareTo` method to implement the operators:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<IComparable, IComparable, bool>> comparisons;
comparisons.add("<", (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y) < 0);
comparisons.add("==", (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y) == 0);
comparisons.add(">", (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y) > 0);
```

This of course gives less limitation to the data that is used, you could for example feed a `string` and a `DateTime` value to the operator delegate, and it compiles just fine. It's not until you run it that it fails.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's perfectly valid to have something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>> comparisons = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>>();

comparisons.Add("<", (x, y) => x < y);
comparisons.Add("==", (x, y) => x == y);
comparisons.Add(">", (x, y) => x > y);
```

In your example though, you need to be using `Func<int, int, bool>`, since you take two parameters and return a boolean value.

You could also put this in a generic implementation, but then you'd need some way of constraining it so that anything must implement <, ==, and > operators.

Comment: Hmmm, I won't just be passing in ints though.  They will always be paired, but it could be pairs of ints, strings, bools, decimals, etc.  Any ideas on how I could keep it generic and perhaps just catch exceptions that may be thrown regarding comparability?

Comment: You can make the types generic as long as you constrain the generic to value types. That should be valid: `Compare<T> where T: ValueType`

Answer (score 0):

```
Func<int, int, bool> t = null;

var comparisons = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>>
                              {
                                  {"<", (x, y) => x < y},
                                  {"==", (x, y) => x == y},
                                  {">", (x, y) => x > y}
                              };

t = comparisons["<"];
 bool result = t(1,2);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You can definitely invoke the method right after accessing it: `comparisons["<"](1,2)` is valid (and working) code.

Comment: I don't think you need the temporary delegate. Calling it directly out of the dictionary works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be done, but you can only do so if all of the generic type parameters are given concrete types.  For example, this works:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>> comparisons = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>>();
```

There's no way to do this (in pseudo-C++ syntax):

```
Dictionary<string, Func<?, ?, bool>> comparisons = new Dictionary<string, Func<?, ?, bool>>();
```

Comment: +1 for C++ reference :D.  I've been wishing for some of the more advanced template features in .Net generics :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point in having T1 and T2; if there different type's you typically can't compare anyway can you?

If you want to keep it generic, you can do something like this (I'm storing the comparisons dictionary in a field here):

```
class MyClass<T> where T:IComparable<T> 
{
    private Dictionary<string, Func<T, T, bool>> comparisons
        = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, T, bool>>
              {
                  {"<", (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y) < 0},
                  {"==", (x, y) => x.Equals(y)},
                  {">", (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y) > 0}
              };
}
```